# Issue with defining multiple time servers for code signing in Install4j 7.0.8

Tags: install4j

According to the [online documentation](https://www.ej-technologies.com/resources/install4j/help/doc/concepts/codeSigning.html) there is a compiler variable (sys.ext.timestampUrl=<URL>) that can be used to define a different time server for code signing than the default, and that this variable can contain multiple URLs separated by semicolons. While I can get this variable to function correctly when passing in a single URL, I cannot get the multiple URLs to function.

I've tried defining the value via **General Settings** > **Compiler Variables**, as well as attempting to override this value in **Media** > **Customize project defaults** > **Compiler variables**, without success.

Is there something intrinsic to the multiple URLs variable that I'm missing? We are currently on version 7.0.8 (build 7248).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This feature is only available since 8.0.5, before that only a single URL could be passed.

Comment: Great - I was afraid that would be the answer. Thank you so much for the quick response.